# My .bash_profile that displays the git branch of the repository doesn't work anymore

Tags: bash, git

Last time I used this was in 2016 with an old version of Mac OS. I'm now using 10.3.1.

```
# This file is sourced by bash for login shells. The following line
# runs your .bashrc and is recommended by the bash info pages.
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] ; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# Get current git branch
function parse_git_branch() {
    BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
    if [ ! "${BRANCH}" == "" ]
    then
            STAT=`parse_git_dirty`
            echo "[${BRANCH}${STAT}] "
    else
            echo ""
    fi
}

# Get repository's current status
function parse_git_dirty {
    status=`git status 2>&1 | tee`
    dirty=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "modified:" &> /dev/null; 
echo "$?"`
    untracked=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Untracked files" &> 
/dev/null; echo "$?"`
    ahead=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Your branch is ahead of" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    newfile=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "new file:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    renamed=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "renamed:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    deleted=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "deleted:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    bits=''
    if [ "${renamed}" == "0" ]; then
            bits=">${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${ahead}" == "0" ]; then
            bits="*${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${newfile}" == "0" ]; then
            bits="+${bits} "
    fi
    if [ "${untracked}" == "0" ]; then
            bits="?${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${deleted}" == "0" ]; then
            bits="x${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${dirty}" == "0" ]; then
            bits="!${bits}"
    fi
    if [ ! "${bits}" == "" ]; then
            echo "${bits}"
    else
            echo ""
    fi
}

# Custom command line
export PS1="\n\[\e[1m\e[38;5;57m\]\w \[\e[0m\e[38;5;66m\]\`parse_git_branch\`\n\[\e[38;5;45m\]\$(date +%H:%M:%S) \[\e[38;5;57m\]» \[\e[38;5;15m\]"

# Custom ls colours
export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;32:'
```

This is what it displays

```
\n\[\e[1m\e[38;5;57m\]\w \[\e[0m\e[38;5;66m\]`parse_git_branch`\n\[\e[38;5;45m\]$(date +:samuels-mbp.lan:) \[\e[38;5;57m\]» \[\e[38;5;15m\]
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145445/discussion-on-question-by-samuel-bacay-my-bash-profile-that-displays-the-git-br); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The problem here was that the OP was using bash code in zsh. Since the question seems to have been abandoned and was based on a misudnerstanding of what shell was being used, I will close as non-reproducible. Samuel, if you don't feel this is answered, please [edit] and add what is currently going on.